# Debian apt install single package from experimental but keep original system upgrades

Tags: debian, apt, pinning

I'v installed xfce 4.12 on debian jessie from testing by adding the testing repo in

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/testing.list`

File content:

```
deb     http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/    testing main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/    testing main contrib non-free
```

I have tried to pin the package to experimental with `/etc/apt/preferences.d/testing.pref` containing:

```
Package: xfce4
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 750
```

Problem is that running `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` I am getting updates from the experimental repo for all installed packages whereas I would like to achieve ugrading xfce from testing and all the rest from jessie stable.

Seeking help to solve this as I do not fully understand the pinning system.

Comment: Just a reminder: While it seems Debian people do this sort of thing all the time, **it is not safe** and can result in a completely unrecoverable system.

Comment: Hi I do know this. I am doing some testing on xfce that is why I'm trying to achieve this

Comment: Or do you think the best option would be to upgrade to stretch which includes xfce 4.12?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't use Debian at all, but if I did it would be a complete stretch installation (or sid, or whatever). Not packages mixed from different releases.

Comment: Good point, will think about it.